# How to generate duplicate rows and enumerate/calculate based on a column value in a DataFrame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I am trying to convert some sas code to python. I feel difficulty to create new column to enumerate and calculate values by looping rows based on a column value.

Original dataset:

[image]

My desired output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I found after research several case in stackoverflow:

df=df.iloc[np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.count)]
df=df.set_index(df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1).reset_index()